# PHP ellipsis using substr and concatenation

Tags: php, arrays

```
    foreach($products as $val)
    {
        $name = $val["name"];

        if(strlen($name) > 5){
             $name = substr($name,0,5) . '..';
        }

}
```

I have a list of string, and I want to add dot dot at the end of it using PHP, but above code return 0?

Comment: This code will replace `$name` each time..

Comment: @Jenz ya I know but I'm stuck..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make changes you need to reference `&` the copy in the foreach.

Example:

```
foreach($products as &$val) {
                 //  ^ reference
    if(strlen($val['name']) > 5) {
        $val['name'] = substr($val['name'], 0, 5) . ' ...';
    }
}
```

Or if you are not comfortable this way, could also use the key of the foreach to point it directly to that index.

```
foreach($products as $key => $val) {
    if(strlen($val['name']) > 5) {
        $products[$key]['name'] = substr($val['name'], 0, 5) . ' ...';
               // ^ use $key
    }
}
```

And lastly, if you do not want any changes at all (just output echo), then this:

```
foreach($products as $key => $val) {
    $name = $val['name'];
    if(strlen($name) > 5) {
        $name = substr($name['name'], 0, 5) . '...';
    }
    echo $name; // you forgot to echo
}
```

Comment: For newbie it would be much more useful to see an example with using `$products[$key]['name']` rather than using references.

Comment: @zerkms yeah i also though of that, thats a good insight indeed

Comment: @user3522888 do you have a sample data that can be used for this example?

Comment: @user3522888 oh okay, check my revision

Answer (score 1):

your question is a bit unclear as to where you are stuck.

If you want to modify your `$products` array, then Ghost offered you one solution.

If you simply want an array of shortened product names, I would store them in a new array since you might need the full names later.

```
$shortNames = array();
foreach($products as $val)
{
    $name = $val["name"];

    if(strlen($name) > 5){
         $name = substr($name,0,5) . '..';
    }
    $shortNames[] = $name;

}
```

You wrote

> but above code return 0

if this code is inside a function, maybe you simple missed to `return` the result?
for example with my code, put `return $shortNames;` at the end of the function